# Getting only time of a datetime object

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to get only the time of a `DateTime` object.

Let's say I have this object:

```
 Nullable<DateTime> data = new DateTime(2007,6,15,5 ,23,45);
```

I tryed using :

```
data.Value.ToShortTimeString()
```

And I recieve:

```
5:23 AM
```

I would like to be able to display only `5:23`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) method with the appropriate [formatting string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx):

```
var time = date.ToString("H:mm");
```

Comment: +1 for fastest right answer.

Comment: give Error like "No overload method for ToString take 1 argument"

Answer (score 4):

You can use  *"H" custom format specifier*.

> The "H" custom format specifier represents the hour as a number from 0
>   through 23; that is, the hour is represented by a zero-based 24-hour
>   clock that counts the hours since midnight. A single-digit hour is
>   formatted without a leading zero.

```
Nullable<DateTime> data = new DateTime(2007, 6, 15, 5, 23, 45);
Console.WriteLine(data.Value.ToString("H:mm"));
```

Output will be;

```
5:23
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/gDNjqg).

For more information, check out [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: Should be `HH` for hours on a 24-hour clock (which would be reasonable without the AM/PM identifier.

Comment: Only other thing (I missed this at first, too), `H` would suit the OPs needs more appropriately as they don't seem to want a leading `0` for single-digit hours.

Answer (score 3):

```
        Nullable<DateTime> data = new DateTime(2007, 6, 15, 5, 23, 45);
        var timeofDay   = data.Value.TimeOfDay; // 05:23:45
```

Comment: For my info. Was the down vote bocoz of the `ss` part?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to get a `TimeSpan` type, use the property in DateTime class called `TimeOfDay`. It returns only the "time" part.

If you need to get a string in that format, using TimeOfDay is an overkill and simply use `ToString("hh:mm")` to format your output. If you don't want results like `05:40`, use `ToString("H:mm")`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var time = date.ToString("H:mm");
```

`H` here represents 24 hour time. i.e. 0-23

See more format [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

strange, it works fine for me, maby it's a setting in visual studio?

You can try this

```
Nullable<DateTime> data = new DateTime(2007, 6, 15, 5, 23, 45);
Debug.Write(data.Value.Hour + ":" + data.Value.Minute);
```

Comment: string s = "Your date";


            DateTime.TryParse(s, out dt);

            string Time = dt.ToString("HH:mm:ss:tt");

          Or

            string t1 = dt.ToString("H:mm");